# Erro ao incluir arquivo dentro da função

Tags: php

Pessoal estou montando um sistema onde quero faze-lo mutipla linguagem...
Bom criei o projeto, dentro dele tem uma pasta strings (onde dentro tem um arquivo chamado PT-BR.php), tem um arquivo funcoes (onde tem uma funcao que passo o nome de arquivo e ele inclui com o include_once), no arquivo que estou fazendo  o teste ao incluir e chamar a funcao ele toda normal, mas quando dou um echo em uma var que esta dentro do arquivo, da erro.
Como posso resolver ? ou existe um metodo mais facil ?
Obrigado

arquivo teste.php

```
<?php
include_once ("class/funcoes.php");
autoLoad();
session_start();
$sl = $_SESSION['lang']; //Passa PT-BR
defineLanguage($sl);
echo $strNome;
```

arquivo class/funcoes.php

```
<?php

    function defineLanguage ($language) {
        $dir = "strings/";
        if($language == "PT-BR") {
            $include = $dir . "PT-BR" . ".php";
            //include_once($include);
            include('strings/PT-BR.php');
        }
    }
```

arquivo strings/PT-BR.php

```
<?php
$strNome = "teste";
```

ERRO

> Notice: Undefined variable: strNome in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/log-u/testeSession.php on line 11

Comment: Pode resolver isso postando o código e a mensagem de erro.

Comment: @rray Coloquei o código...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o include é feito dentro da função, logo todas as variáveis definidas nela e as do include ficam restritas a função como nada é retornado ocorre o `undefined variable`.

Faça dirente, na sua função retorne o caminho do arquivo de localização(talvez seja necessário definar constantes com o caminho dos diretorios raiz e de localização), use o retorno como argumento do include/require.

Função:

```
function defineLanguage ($language) {
    $dir = "strings/";
    if($language == "PT-BR") {
        return $dir . "PT-BR" . ".php";
    }
}
```

Chamada:

```
<?php
include_once ("class/funcoes.php");
autoLoad();
session_start();
$sl = $_SESSION['lang']; //Passa PT-BR
$arquivo = defineLanguage($sl);
require_once($arquivo); //<--- linha adicionada
echo $strNome;
```

Comment: funcionou... mas não tem uma maneira onde posso pegar esse codigo para não ficar replicando em todas as pgs ?

Comment: @AugustoFurlan essa parte da definição da linguagem você colocar em um arquivo separado e fazer include/require dele nos demais ou se estiver fazendo o site instituicional, com textos fixos e poucas páginas pode carregar tudo na sessão.

Comment: ok obrigado @rray